# get original entity from EntityStream

Tags: jax-rs

I'm using Jax RS 2.0 **ContainerRequestFilter**

I want to intercept entity body (if any) and convert to original type.

I can get original class type by using inkected **ResourceInfo**

```
resinfo.getResourceMethod().getParameters()
```

However I have no idea on how to get parameter value...

The only closes object is an **EntityStream()**, available from:

```
containerRequestContext.getEntityStream()
```

I guess I should use the above object, but how I can rebuild original object from entityStream ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, it is enought to implement **ReaderInterceptor** interface:

```
@Override
public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext readerInterceptorContext) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    final Object proceed = readerInterceptorContext.proceed();
    return proceed;
}
```